# two mongoDB version commands returning different versions

Tags: mongodb

when i am running `mongo -version` it showing a different version than when i am running `db.version()` from Mongo shell. how this is possible and which is the correct version.

Comment: So what do they say exactly? How do you access the Mongo shell?

Comment: this is the out put of  db.version()
3.2.20
and below 
mongo -version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12

Comment: i am accessing mongo shell from terminal by running mongo command

Answer (score 0):

`mongo -version` returns Mongo shell version.

`db.version()` returns version of the server you're connected to.